# Combine filter() and startsWith() to filter array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Suppose I have an array constant as follows:

```
const people = [
      { first: 'John', last: 'Doe', year: 1991, month: 6 },
      { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe', year: 1990, month: 9 },
      { first: 'Jahn', last: 'Deo', year: 1986, month: 1 },
      { first: 'Jone', last: 'Deo', year: 1992, month: 11 },
      { first: 'Jhan', last: 'Doe', year: 1989, month: 4 },
      { first: 'Jeon', last: 'Doe', year: 1992, month: 2 },
      { first: 'Janh', last: 'Edo', year: 1984, month: 7 },
      { first: 'Jean', last: 'Edo', year: 1981, month: 8},
];
```

And I want to return a value of everyone born in the 80s.

My current working function for achieving this is:

```
const eighty = people.filter(person=> {
    if (person.year >= 1980 && person.year <= 1989) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

---

**My Question:** Is it possible to use [startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) along with [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to replace:

```
if (person.year >= 1980 && person.year <= 1989) {
    return true;
}
```

with **`startsWith('198')`** instead?

If yes, what would be the right way to do it?

Comment: youd have to convert it to a string first...but it would also then cover a year of 19801 for example which is invalid

Comment: Instead of `startsWith`, you could avoid the mentioned edge case by matching a regex instead. Maybe `/^198\d$/.test(String(year))`

Comment: You don’t need this `if` statement. Just return the condition: `people.filter((person) => person.year >= 1980 && person.year <= 1989)` or use destructuring: `people.filter(({year}) => year >= 1980 && year <= 1989)`.

Comment: `return Math.floor(person.year / 10) === 198`

Comment: My basic problem is that these alternate solutions save you like half a line of code, and in exchange it's either a massive overhead (converting to string + checking a substring) compared to a simple value check, or in the case of `Math.floor()`, it's really unintuitive to read. I'd recommend you go with @Xufox's suggestion and just return the boolean expression instead of using an `if` branch.

Comment: @MátéSafranka for readability, use any of the solutions and put it into a `isInThe1980s(year)` function. Then you can use it again in other places and it makes it possible to write a couple of sanity-checking tests if you wanted to :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do

```
people.filter(person => String(person.year).startsWith('198'))
```

```js
const people = [
      { first: 'John', last: 'Doe', year: 1991, month: 6 },
      { first: 'Jane', last: 'Doe', year: 1990, month: 9 },
      { first: 'Jahn', last: 'Deo', year: 1986, month: 1 },
      { first: 'Jone', last: 'Deo', year: 1992, month: 11 },
      { first: 'Jhan', last: 'Doe', year: 1989, month: 4 },
      { first: 'Jeon', last: 'Doe', year: 1992, month: 2 },
      { first: 'Janh', last: 'Edo', year: 1984, month: 7 },
      { first: 'Jean', last: 'Edo', year: 1981, month: 8},
];

var filtered = people.filter(p => String(p.year).startsWith('198'));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: sorry for that mistake... p.year or person.year whatever you are using

Answer (score 5):

This isn't quite what you asked, sorry, but if you're interested in solving the problem in one operation rather than using `startsWith` specifically, you can do it numerically...

`Math.floor(person.year / 10) === 198`

It may be slighly more efficient as no string conversion and doesn't have the problems of other strings starting the same way matching.

Comment: That would help avoid the edge case of it being larger than `1989`.

Comment: +1 This is definitely more reliable and straightforward and I think I'll definitely go with this when working with filtering arrays @brabster, but Zohaib's answer showed me a way to combine the two methods as I initially wanted to know so I'm giving him the tick man. Cheers.

Comment: Good call pal happy to help ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can:

```
people.filter(person => String(person.year).startsWith('198'));
```

However, you probably don't want to because you could run into weird things where the year isn't valid (like if it was `19812`).

Instead, you'd be better off using regex:

```
people.filter(person => /^198\d$/.test(person.year));
```

This will only match the years in the 1980s. You also don't have to do the extra cast, so its a little cleaner too.

Comment: +1 Thank you @samanime! Will be using `Math.floor` or `regex` instead of `startsWith()` for filtering numbered arrays.